# Custom forms authentication using login from parent domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, subdomain

I have an parent MVC site that handles logins that has the domain mysite.com. This is basically the template MVC internet application out of the box - a user logs in, and it sets an .ASPXAUTH cookie with the domain .mysite.com.

I also have another MVC site that runs on the domain child.mysite.com. I intend to use custom forms authentication to authenticate the user from the cookie set by the parent. When I browse to child.mysite.com in Firefox, I can see the cookie set by the login site in Firebug, so I know the child site can access it, but I do not seem to be able to retreive this cookie from my code in the child site.

I am implementing FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate in Global.asax, and I would have expected the cookie to be visible in Request.Cookies, but there are no cookies there.

How do I access the cookie set by the parent login site in FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the problem. The child site was finding the cookie, but when it tried to decrypt it, it was erroring, and therefore not authenticating fully. This code on the child site would thow and error:

```
void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    var cookie = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
}
```

The error is 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed' and is due to the fact that the child site cannot decrypt the cookie set by the parent site.

The answer is to set the machine key in system.web in web.config to be the same for both sites:

```
<machineKey 
    validationKey='241FF35BE3921690EBA492A89CC03719ECF5552D019448C44F8B28B01F546FCDC4AEDCD273380EB45BE8A49AFB9C14FE60BECF0B5ECBA4901C306875FED98DEA'
decryptionKey='864559FC58AC5FFB5B9581008552B4A873ACBE86469A81CB'
validation='SHA1'/>
```